# Python imports within a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory, python-import

I have a project that is structured thus:

```
.
  |-dir
  |  |-subdir
  |  |  |-subsubdir1
  |  |  |-subsubdir2
  |  |  |-subsubdir3
  |  |  |-sub_sub_main.py
  |  |  |-other_relevant.py
  |  |-sub_main1.py
  |-dir2
  |  |-sub_main2.py
  |-main.py
```

Sometimes I need to import functions from `other_relevant.py` in `main.py`, `sub_main1.py`, `sub_main2.py`, and `sub_sub_main.py`. However, importing the script from different levels of the directory tree causes for the necessary import structure to change.

The code in `other_relevant.py` and `sub_sub_main.py` relies on code in other python files in `subsubdir1`, `subsubdir2`, and `subsubdir3`. When I change where I import those two files the import statements in all the python files in those subdirectories have to be changed.

If I run `main.py` or `sub_main2.py` which imports `other_relevant.py`, it requires the import in `other_relevant.py` to use `from dir.subdir1.subsubdir1.file import ...`.

If I am running the `sub_main.py` script then the import statement becomes `from subdir.subsubdir1.file import ...`

If I run `sub_sub_main.py` then the import statement becomes `from subsubdir1.file import ...`.

Since the file structure makes sense in terms of how to organize the files I don't want to really change that. Is there a way to manage the import statements so that I don't have to change all the import statements in the files in `subdir` depending on where I run `sub_sub_main.py` and `other_relevant.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the env variable `PYTHONPATH` to your top folder path. Then all import statement will be made relative to this folder wherever you execute a python script.
For instance from `sub_main2.py` you can do:

```
from dir.subdir.subdir3 import *
```

Setting up the env variable can be done by sourcing a sourceme.sh file located at the folder path. or directly in the .bashrc if only one project is used.

sample *sourceme.sh:*

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd -P`
```

Comment: Could this be added to the bashrc file?